# How do the privacy settings work in Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

If my profile is set to *private*, is it visible to me only, or to employers as well?

I'd like to have it both searchable and visible to employers, but at the same time not to share it publicly on the web or even with other Stack Overflow users.

Currently it's set to *private*, but I've also chosen the *Looking for a job* status, so I'm not sure what the final effect is. The nomenclature is quite confusing.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I agree the terminology isn't the clearest.

**Employer view** affects your profile visibility for employers only. Setting this to "searchable" means that your profile is visible to employers. Setting this to "blocked" means your profile will not appear in employer searches. This does not preclude you from having a public profile however.

**Privacy settings** allow you to share your profile with others. If the setting is set to "public", you are able to create a custom URL for your profile. This allows you to publicly share your profile. Setting this to "private" does not mean your profile will not appear in employer searches. It just means you will be unable to share your profile with others.

Comment: There isn't a "Employer view" anymore.